# Using PrincipalContext to search LDAP (Active Directory) for all usernames, and their information

Tags: vb.net, ldap, ldap-query, principalcontext

I'm having problems with this code... apparently, it works, but is too slow for me, does anyone have any ideas? It slows down when I try to get access the following

```
Dim u As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, p.SamAccountName)
```

Again, the following code works just fine, but it's slow as crap. If I take out the above, piece of code and just search for `p.SamAccountName` it's done within 1 second, so I'm sure I'm doing something incorrect.

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    sw.Start()

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Account Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "First Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Last Name"

    Dim ctx = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "JOI", DomainName)
    Dim userPrin As New UserPrincipal(ctx)
    userPrin.Name = "*"
    Dim searcher = New System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher()
    searcher.QueryFilter = userPrin
    Dim results = searcher.FindAll()

    For Each p As Principal In results
        Dim u As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, p.SamAccountName)
        Dim row As String() = New String() {u.SamAccountName, u.GivenName, u.Surname}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    sw.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show("Finished in :" & sw.Elapsed.Duration.Seconds & " seconds")

End Sub

Private Shared Function DomainName() As String

    Dim objRootDSE As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
    DomainName = objRootDSE.Properties("defaultNamingContext")(0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to the `UserPrincipal` in your result from the search and then you are performing another new search for each item in the result. That is exactly what is slowing down your function.

I usually filter the filter (LINQ) and only take result items that are of `UserPrincipal` type. That way it's just one pass through search

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    sw.Start()

    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Account Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "First Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Last Name"

    Using context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "JOI", DomainName)
        Using userPrin As UserPrincipal = New UserPrincipal(context)
            userPrin.Name = "*"
            Using searcher As PrincipalSearcher = New PrincipalSearcher(userPrin)

                Dim results = searcher _
                    .FindAll() _
                    .OfType(Of UserPrincipal)()

                For Each p As UserPrincipal In results
                    Dim row As String() = New String() {p.SamAccountName, p.GivenName, p.Surname}
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    sw.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show("Finished in :" & sw.Elapsed.Duration.Seconds & " seconds")

End Sub
```

Comment: Testing this now, though after looking through what you're doing I see my issue... cannot believe I didn't see that. Still learning though, thanks. Will post as solution as soon as I test in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Works like a charm, went from 10 seconds, to 1 for entire AD structure.